# Stripe API - No data in response

Tags: .net, rest, stripe-payments

I'm using the Stripe .Net API and I'd like to present my customer a list of their invoice history along with the relevant receipts.  When I make the curl request to

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/invoices?limit=3 -u <SecretKey> -G
```

the  request does not return any data. What am I doing wrong? Is it becuase i am currently in the test mode?

[image]

Comment: This simply means that you don't have any invoices in Test mode on this Stripe account. If you create a customer and a subscription in Test mode you would see an invoice returned

Comment: @koopajah, i dont understand, i have three payments made on the payment account and i have an invoice generated at https://dashboard.stripe.com/emails/receipts/pmtrc_1DT0nqJXVZLPonCYvvoOWaOg. In this case should not 3 invoices be returned back?

Comment: @AjitGoel those are Payment Receipts, not Invoices. Unfortunately receipts are not currently available in the API, only through the dashboard.